# Maximizing and minimizing a function with x and y

Tags: calculus, optimization, quadratics, maxima-minima

It is clear that 253x + 256y = 253(x+y) + 3y. For a pair of integers x and y satisfying: $$253x + 256y = 1$$

The absolute value of x is minimum. Then, x = ? and y = ?

I tried squaring the equation to make it a quadratic, and seeing if I can make a graph of it from there, but that didn't work as my variables always cancelled out. I thought about trying to do a calculus maximization/minimization but I have no idea on how to even start when all I'm given is two of the exact same equation.

All help is appreciated! The answers are x = 85 and y = -84

Comment: Do you know about [Bézout's identity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) and the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)? Or are you insisting on approaching this as a calculus optimization problem?

Comment: No, I just have to solve the problem. I actually have no idea if it is calculus or not, just assumed it was.

Comment: I am a little familiar with linear algebra, though I have only taken about 1/4 of the full course. Know about where I can learn about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. I don't much like the "back-substitution" step, I prefer  to get the desired Bezout identity through continued fractions.   The last line below says $ 256 \cdot 84 - 253 \cdot 85 = -1 .$  This confirms that the two numbers are coprime. In turn this says  that all such relations can be expressed as

$ 256 \cdot (84  + 253 t) - 253 \cdot (85 + 256t) = -1 .$
You want $+1$   so

$$ -256 \cdot (84  + 253 t) + 253 \cdot (85 + 256t) = 1 .$$
Then we see $x = 85 + 256 t.$  The values of $x$ with modest absolute value are $t=-2, t=-1, t=0, t=1$   or
$x= -427, -171, 85, 341$  so that the minimum absolute value is **$x=85. \; $**  This happens when $t=0$  so the coefficient of $256$  is $y=-84$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \gcd( 256, 253 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 256 }{ 253 } = 1 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 253 } $$
$$ \frac{ 253 }{ 3 } = 84 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 } $$
$$ \frac{ 3 }{ 1 } = 3 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 84 & & 3 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 85 }{ 84 }   & &   \frac{ 256 }{ 253 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 256 \cdot 84 - 253 \cdot 85 = -1 $$

Comment: Ok so what I've seen on here and youtube is that this is just long division plus remainders, where you first find the GCF without the variables, then you rewrite the equation using the numbers that you found while finding the GCF. For example, if the equation was something = 1, then the equation that has + 1 as a remainder in it would be used to solve that equation. Right?

Comment: How did you make that fraction table?

Comment: @TizzleRizzle  this is called a continued fraction. It is a useful method to know. The fractions $\frac{1}{1}, \frac{85}{84}, \frac{256}{253}$ are called the convergents . When approximating an irrational number, the continued fraction keeps going forever.

Comment: what does being coprime have to do with anything?

Answer (score 4):

You can start with $z=x+y$ so you rewrite your system as $253z+3y=1$. Then you can say that $w=84z+y$ so you have $3w+z=1$. So solutions are like:
$$w=-1,z=4$$
or
$$w=0,z=1$$
or
$$w=1,z=-2$$
Working backward, you can see that your solution is correct.

To see more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation